# Can I install Spaces and Exposé on Lion?

Tags: macos, spaces, mission-control, expose

Like many of you, I'm sure, Mission Control isn't quite cutting it for me in Lion. I much preferred Spaces and Exposé. So, naturally, I tried reinstalling them on Lion. I got Spaces.app, Expose.app, and Expose&Spaces.prefpane from a machine running Snow Leopard, and tried installing them in System Prefs and the Applications folder.

It didn't work. Every time you open up the Spaces and Exposé prefpane, it shows the Mission Control pane. Double-clicking on Spaces.app brought up Mission Control, even if you change the name.

**Any idea on how to install Spaces and Exposé on Lion?**

Comment: I agree! The old method is much better than the new!

Comment: since your pretty much stuck with Mission Control in Lion, i may as well recommend the <kbd> option </kbd> feature in MIssion control. While in mission control, <kbd> option </kbd> click a space on the top to view it mission control, but NOT switch to it. This allows for a similar functionality to using spaces and expose together at the same time to quickly rearrange windows.

Comment: Woah! That helps a ton... Thanks for the tip! That makes Mission Control actually work for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible because Mission Control / Spaces / Exposé are **actually controlled by the Dock**. And you'll certainly have no end of trouble if you try to transplant the Dock between OS versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, it's Mission Control all the way. I'm actually quite happy with it, and made a pretty seamless transition. What features are you missing? You can do everything with Mission Control that you could do with Spaces and Exposé, with the sole exception of Spaces in rows. You can even assign applications to individual spaces; that option is in the app's dock icon now.

Comment: I miss 2 things. I liked the grid: you could get to any space quickly and visually, and it told you where you were each time you switched. I also liked being able to move any window from any space to any other space. And, I dislike the new animation. It's nauseating.

Comment: What can I say, there's nothing you can do about it, except downgrade to Snow Leopard. Well on the flip side, I like some of the new changes: I can create or delete Spaces anytime, even creating a new space by dragging an app on to that Plus space. Spaces and Expose are unified. Also I can switch between spaces with gestures, and assign different wallpapers to each space.

Comment: I miss Expose all Windows, the ability to rearrange spaces at will & the ability to move the entire contents of a space into another one

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem
but all is there,
just need to configure it [ I use the hot corner method]

[Mission control Lion Tutorial](http://iakobou.wordpress.com/2011/08/06/mission-control-lion-tutorial/)

Comment: -1 broken link (hence this answer is no longer useful)